# Compass not compiling in sublime text 2

Tags: sass, sublimetext2, compass-sass, compass

Getting the following error when I'm trying to save my scss files:

```
File to import not found or unreadable: compass. (Sass::SyntaxError)
```

My Sass builder config:

```
{
    "output_path": "../css",
    "options": {
        "cache":         true,
        "debug":         true,
        "line-comments": true,
        "line-numbers":  true,
        "style":         "nested"
    }
}
```

Installed the following packages with my Sublime Text 2:
https://github.com/bnlucas/SassBuilder
https://github.com/WhatWeDo/Sublime-Text-2-Compass-Build-System

So the question is, what am I doing wrong here? Do I need to add something in my build config?

Thanks in advance!